# CSS sprites, assigning class names

Tags: html, css

Which is more appropriate.

(a) To have a common class "sprite" that will always be used with another class to pick coordinates, or (b) to simply assign the same properties to a list of classes?

(a) This makes more sense, because it simply less code and is probably faster. The down side is that this introduces need for (theoretically) only-CSS developer to interact with HTML.

```
.sprite { background: url('[..]') no-repeat; display: block; }
.sprite.a { background-position: [..]; }
.sprite.b { background-position: [..]; }
```

(b)

```
.a,
.b { background: url('[..]') no-repeat; display: block; }
.sprite.a { background-position: [..]; }
.sprite.b { background-position: [..]; }
```

Am I forgetting anything? Which one should I use?

Answer (score 2):

I would use the `sprite` class to select the background image (and possibly other common properties such as the size if all sprites have the same size) and then additional classes that only specify the background-position.

This keeps the stylesheet readable and smaller since you don't have to repeat your class name all the time.

Comment: This is the way to go :). I have seen it in gmail and personally use it too